# When run the code on trigger change I get an error "Auto Move Rows Cannot read property 'getLastRow' of undefined Code line: 559"

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have an issue with trying to run a script named 'moveRowsFromSpreadsheetToSpreadsheet_ version 2.7' the script will run perfect when he on_edit trigger is installed however when I try to run the script using the on_change trigger it returns an error the sheet "Auto Move Rows Cannot read property 'getlastRow' of undefined code line:267.

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated on how to get the script to run on_change trigger.
Thanks in advance

```
/**
* Global variables.
*/
try {
  ////////////////////////////////
  // [START modifiable parameters]
  var sheetsToWatch =       ['QUOTATIONS'];
  var columnsToWatch =      ['STATUS', 'STATUS'];
  var valuesToWatch =       [/^(CONFIRMED)$/i, /^(PENDING)$/i];
  var targetSheets =        ['DELIVERIES', 'PENDING'];
  var targetSpreadheets =   ['165PYmS-NkEqM7kSBhZ7EjMF4CIhxvdaIQJB6meJd-DE',
                             '165PYmS-NkEqM7kSBhZ7EjMF4CIhxvdaIQJB6meJd-DE'];
  var targetIdColumn =      [];
  var targetValues =        [];
  var transferTypes =       ['PASTE_NORMAL'];
  var allowArrayFormulas =  [true, true];
  var copyInsteadOfMove =   [true, true];
  var numColumnsToMove =    [];
  var changeColumnOrderTo = [];
  var sheetsToSort =        ['Target'];
  var columnToSortBy =      [3];
  var sortAscending =       [true];
  // [END modifiable parameters]
  ////////////////////////////////
} catch (error) {
  showAndThrow_(error);
}
  


/**
* Moves rows from sheet to sheet, and sorts the source and target sheets after the move.
*
* @param {Object} e The onEdit event object.
*/
function moveRowsAndSortSheet_(e) {
  // version 1.1, written by --Hyde, 27 June 2020
  //  - use LockService
  //  - sort all targetSheets instead of sorting just one targetSheet
  // version 1.0, written by --Hyde, 9 January 2020
  //  - initial version
  try {
    var lock = LockService.getDocumentLock();
    lock.waitLock(30 * 1000);
    var modifiedSheets = moveRowsFromSpreadsheetToSpreadsheet_(e);
    if (modifiedSheets) {
      [modifiedSheets.sourceSheet].concat(modifiedSheets.targetSheets).forEach(function (sheet) {
        sortSheet_(sheet);
      });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    showAndThrow_(error);
  } finally {
    lock.releaseLock();
  }
}

/**
* Moves a row from a spreadsheet to another spreadsheet file when a magic value is entered in a column.
*
* The name of the sheet to move the row to is derived from the position of the magic value on the valuesToWatch list.
* The targetSpreadheets list uses spreadsheet IDs that can be obtained from the address bar of the browser.
* Use a spreadsheet ID of '' to indicate that the row is to be moved to another tab in the same spreadsheet file.
*
* Globals: see the Global variables section.
* Displays pop-up messages through Spreadsheet.toast().
* Throws errors.
*
* @param {Object} e The 'on edit', 'on form submit' or 'on change' event object.
* @return {Object} An object that lists the sheets that were modified with this structure, or a falsy value if no rows were moved:
*                  {Sheet} sourceSheet The sheet from where a row was moved.
*                  {Sheet[]} targetSheets The sheets to where rows were moved.
*                  {Number} numRowsMoved The number of rows that were moved to another sheet.
*/
function moveRowsFromSpreadsheetToSpreadsheet_(e) {
  
  var event = getEventObject_(e);
  if (!event || sheetsToWatch.indexOf(event.sheetName) === -1) {
    return;
  }
  if (targetIdColumn.length) {
    var targetIdColumnNumber = event.columnLabels.indexOf(targetIdColumn[0]) + 1;
    if (!targetIdColumnNumber || !targetValues.length) {
      throw new Error('Could not find target values in target column "' + String(targetIdColumn[0]) + '".');
    }
    var valuesInTargetIdColumn = event.sheet.getRange(event.rowStart, targetIdColumnNumber, event.numRows, 1).getDisplayValues();
  }
  var numRowsMoved = 0;
  var messageOnDisplay = false;
  var sourceSheetNames = [];
  var targetSheetNames = [];
  var targets = [];
  for (var row = event.numRows - 1; row >= 0; row--) {
    for (var column = 0; column < event.numColumns; column++) {
      if (event.rowStart + row <= event.columnLabelRow || columnsToWatch.indexOf(event.columnLabels[event.columnStart - 1 + column]) === -1) {
        continue;
      }
      var valuesToWatchIndex = -1;
      for (var i = 0, numRegexes = valuesToWatch.length; i < numRegexes; i++) {
        if (event.displayValues[row][column].match(valuesToWatch[i])) {
          valuesToWatchIndex = i;
          break;
        }
      }
      if (valuesToWatchIndex === -1) {
        continue;
      }
      var targetIndex = -1;
      if (targetIdColumn.length) {
        for (var i = 0, numRegexes = targetValues.length; i < numRegexes; i++) {
          if (valuesInTargetIdColumn[row][0].match(targetValues[i])) {
            targetIndex = i;
            break;
          }
        }
      } else {
        targetIndex = valuesToWatchIndex;
      }  
      if (targetIndex === -1) {
        continue;
      }
      if (!messageOnDisplay) {
        showMessage_('Moving rows...', 30);
        messageOnDisplay = true;
      }
      var targetSheet = getTargetSheet_(event, targetIndex);
      if (!targetSheet) {
        continue; // skip moving the row if it would end up on the same sheet
      }
      var sourceRange = event.sheet.getRange(event.rowStart + row, 1, 1, event.numSheetColumns);
      var transferType = transferTypes[targetIndex];
      var firstFreeTargetRow = targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1;
      if (firstFreeTargetRow > targetSheet.getMaxRows()) {
        targetSheet.insertRowAfter(targetSheet.getLastRow());
      }
      var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(firstFreeTargetRow, 1);
      switch (transferType) {
        case 'PASTE_VALUES':
        case undefined:
          var rowValues = rearrangeRowValues_(sourceRange, targetIndex);
          targetSheet.appendRow(rowValues);
          break;
        case 'PASTE_FORMAT':
          // @see https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/copy-paste-type
          sourceRange.copyTo(targetRange, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType[transferType], false);
          sourceRange.copyTo(targetRange, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
          break;
        case 'PASTE_FORMULA':
        case 'PASTE_NORMAL':
        case 'PASTE_NO_BORDERS':
          sourceRange.copyTo(targetRange, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType[transferType], false);
          break;
        default:
          throw new Error('Unknown transferType "' + transferType + '".');
      }
      // clear cells in targetRange where column label row contains an array formula
      if (allowArrayFormulas[targetIndex]) {
        var numColumns = sourceRange.getWidth();
        var formulas = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getFrozenRows() || 1, 1, 1, numColumns).getFormulas()[0];
        formulas.forEach(function (formula, index) {
          if (formula.match(/^=.*arrayformula/i)) {
            targetRange.offset(0, index, 1, 1).clearContent();
          }
        });
      }
      numRowsMoved += 1;
      if (!copyInsteadOfMove[targetIndex]) {
        if (event.sheet.getMaxRows() <= event.columnLabelRow + 1) { // avoid deleting the last unfrozen row
          event.sheet.appendRow([null]);
        }
        event.sheet.deleteRow(event.rowStart + row);
      }
      sourceSheetNames = sourceSheetNames.concat(event.sheetName).filter(filterUniques_);
      targetSheetNames = targetSheetNames.concat(targetSheet.getName()).filter(filterUniques_);
      targets = targets.concat(targetSheet).filter(filterUniques_);
    } // column
  } // row
  if (messageOnDisplay) {
    var message = 'Moved ' + numRowsMoved + (numRowsMoved === 1 ? ' row ' : ' rows ') + "from '" + sourceSheetNames.join(', ') + "' to '" + targetSheetNames.join(', ') + "'.";
    showMessage_('Moving rows... done. ' + message);
  }
  return numRowsMoved ? { sourceSheet: event.sheet, targetSheets: targets, numRowsMoved: numRowsMoved } : null;
}

/**
* Sorts a sheet.
*
* Globals: sheetsToSort, columnToSortBy, sortAscending.
*
* @param {Sheet} sheet The sheet to sort.
*/
function sortSheet_(sheet) {
  // version 1.0, written by --Hyde, 19 March 2020
  //  - initial version
  var sheetIndex = sheetsToSort.indexOf(sheet.getName());
  if (sheetIndex === -1) {
    return;
  }
  sheet.sort(columnToSortBy[sheetIndex], sortAscending[sheetIndex]);
}

/**
* Determines the type of a spreadsheet event and populates an event object.
*
* Globals: valuesToWatch.
*
* [NOTE] Could add these fields: value, oldValue, values.
*
* @param {Object} e The original event object.
* @return {Object} An event object with the following fields, or null if the event type is unknown.
*                  {Spreadsheet} spreadsheet The spreadsheet that was edited.
*                  {Sheet} sheet The sheet that was edited in spreadsheet.
*                  {Range} range The cell or range that was edited in sheet.
*                  {String} sheetName The name of the sheet that was edited.
*                  {Number} rowStart The ordinal number of the first row in range.
*                  {Number} rowEnd The ordinal number of the last row in range.
*                  {Number} columnStart The ordinal number of the first column in range.
*                  {Number} columnEnd The ordinal number of the last column in range.
*                  {Number} numRows The number of rows in range.
*                  {Number} numColumns The number of columns in range.
*                  {String} changeType Always EDIT, and never INSERT_ROW, INSERT_COLUMN, REMOVE_ROW, REMOVE_COLUMN, INSERT_GRID, REMOVE_GRID, FORMAT, or OTHER.
*                  {String} authMode One of ScriptApp.AuthMode.NONE, .LIMITED, .FULL or .CUSTOM_FUNCTION.
*                  {String[][]} displayValues The values in range as shown in the spreadsheet as text strings.
*                  {Number} numSheetColumns The number of columns in sheet.
*                  {Number} columnLabelRow The 1-based row number where column labels are found.
*                  {String[]} columnLabels The values in row event.columnLabelRow as shown in the spreadsheet as text strings.
*/
function getEventObject_(e) {
  // version 1.1, written by --Hyde, 29 July 2020
  //  - use Number()
  // version 1.0, written by --Hyde, 27 July 2020
  //  - initial version
  if (!e || !valueIsPlainObject_(e)) {
    return null;
  }
  var event = {};
  if (e.range && JSON.stringify(e.range) !== '{}') { // triggered by ScriptApp.EventType.ON_EDIT or .ON_FORM_SUBMIT
    if (e.value === '') { // optimization for single-cell edits
      return null;
    }
    if (e.value !== undefined) { // optimization for single-cell edits
      var valuesToWatchIndex = -1;
      for (var i = 0, numRegexes = valuesToWatch.length; i < numRegexes; i++) {
        if (e.value.match(valuesToWatch[i])) {
          valuesToWatchIndex = i;
          break;
        }
      }
      if (valuesToWatchIndex === -1) {
        return null;
      }
    }
    event.range = e.range;
    event.rowStart = Number(e.range.rowStart);
    event.rowEnd = Number(e.range.rowEnd);
    event.columnStart = Number(e.range.columnStart);
    event.columnEnd = Number(e.range.columnEnd);
    event.changeType = 'EDIT';
    event.eventType = e.namedValues ? 'ON_FORM_SUBMIT' : 'ON_EDIT';'ON_CHANGE';
  } else if (e.changeType === 'EDIT') { // triggered by ScriptApp.EventType.ON_CHANGE
    
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    event.range = ss.getActiveRange();
    event.rowStart = event.range.getRow();
    event.rowEnd = e.range.getLastRow(1);
    event.columnStart = event.range.getColumn();
    event.columnEnd = e.range.getLastRow();
    event.changeType = e.changeType;
    event.eventType = 'ON_CHANGE';
  } else { // triggered by some other change type
    return null;
  }
  event.authMode = e.authMode; // 
  event.displayValues = event.range.getDisplayValues();
  event.sheet = event.range.getSheet();
  event.sheetName = event.sheet.getName();
  event.spreadsheet = event.sheet.getParent();
  event.numRows = event.rowEnd - event.rowStart + 1;
  event.numColumns = event.columnEnd - event.columnStart + 1;
  event.columnLabelRow = event.sheet.getFrozenRows() || 1;
  event.numSheetColumns = event.sheet.getLastColumn();
  event.columnLabels = event.sheet.getRange(event.columnLabelRow, 1, 1, event.numSheetColumns).getDisplayValues()[0];
  return event;
}

function valueIsPlainObject_(value) {
  // version 1.0, written by --Hyde, 26 June 2020
  //  - initial version
  var type = typeof value;
  if (type === 'function' || Array.isArray(value)) {
    return false;
  }
  return type === 'object' && !!value;
}


function filterUniques_(element, index, array) {
  // version 1.0, written by --Hyde, 30 May 2019
  //  - initial version
  return array.indexOf(element) === index;
}


function rearrangeRowValues_(range, targetIndex) {
  // version 1.0, written by --Hyde, 27 June 2020
  //  - initial version, based on inline code in moveRowsFromSpreadsheetToSpreadsheet_
  var rowValuesInOriginalOrder = range.getValues()[0];
  if (numColumnsToMove[targetIndex] !== undefined) {
    var rowValues = rowValuesInOriginalOrder.slice(0, numColumnsToMove[targetIndex]);
  } else {
    rowValues = rowValuesInOriginalOrder.slice();
  }
  for (var changeIndex = 0; changeIndex < changeColumnOrderTo.length; changeIndex++) {
    if (changeColumnOrderTo[changeIndex] !== undefined) {
      rowValues[changeIndex] = rowValuesInOriginalOrder[changeColumnOrderTo[changeIndex]];
    } else if (rowValues[changeIndex] === undefined) {
      rowValues[changeIndex] = null;
    }
  }
  return rowValues;
}


function getTargetSheet_(event, targetIndex) {
  // version 1.0, written by --Hyde, 27 June 2020
  //  - initial version, based on inline code in moveRowsFromSpreadsheetToSpreadsheet_
  var targetSheetName = targetSheets[targetIndex];
  var targetSpreadsheetId = String(targetSpreadheets[targetIndex] || '');
  if (targetSpreadsheetId) {
    try {
      var targetSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(targetSpreadsheetId);
    } catch (error) {
      var ssIdShortened
      = targetSpreadsheetId.length > 13
      ? targetSpreadsheetId.slice(0, 5) + '...' + targetSpreadsheetId.slice(-5)
      : targetSpreadsheetId;
      throw new Error('Could not open a target spreadsheet with ID "' + ssIdShortened + '".');
    }
  } else {
    targetSpreadsheet = event.spreadsheet;
    if (targetSheetName === event.sheetName) {
      return null; // skip moving the row if it would end up in the same sheet
    }
  }
  var targetSheet = targetSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(targetSheetName);
  if (!targetSheet) {
    throw new Error("Could not find the target sheet '" + targetSheetName + "'"
                    + targetSpreadsheet === event.spreadsheet
                    ? '.'
                    : ' in spreadsheet "' + targetSpreadsheet.getName() + '".');
  }
  return targetSheet;
}

/**
* Installs a trigger that runs each time the user hand edits the spreadsheet.
* Deletes any previous instances of ON_EDIT and ON_CHANGE triggers.
*
* To permanently install the trigger, choose Run > Run function > installOnEditTrigger.
* You only need to install the trigger once per spreadsheet.
* To review the installed triggers, choose Edit > Current project's triggers.
*/
function installOnEditTrigger() {
  // version 1.0, written by --Hyde, 7 May 2020
  //  - initial version
  deleteTriggers_(ScriptApp.EventType.ON_EDIT);
  deleteTriggers_(ScriptApp.EventType.ON_CHANGE);
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('moveRowsAndSortSheet_')
  .forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActive())
  .onEdit()
  .create();  
}



/**
* Installs a trigger that runs each time a change is done by Glide, IFTTT, Zapier or other such tools.
* Deletes any previous instances of ON_EDIT and ON_CHANGE triggers.
* [NOTE] This trigger will also move rows when you hand edit the spreadsheet.
* [NOTE] Tested with Glide, but untested with IFTTT, Zapier.
*
* To permanently install the trigger, choose Run > Run function > installOnChangeTrigger.
* You only need to install the trigger once per spreadsheet.
* To review the installed triggers, choose Edit > Current project's triggers.
*/
function installOnChangeTrigger() {
  // version 1.0, written by --Hyde, 7 May 2020
  //  - initial version
  deleteTriggers_(ScriptApp.EventType.ON_EDIT);
  deleteTriggers_(ScriptApp.EventType.ON_CHANGE);
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('moveRowsAndSortSheet_')
  .forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActive())
  .onChange()
  .create();
}

/**
* Deletes all installable triggers of the type triggerType associated with the current
* script project that are owned by the current user in the current spreadsheet.
*
* @param {EventType} triggerType One of ScriptApp.EventType.ON_EDIT, .ON_FORM_SUBMIT, .ON_OPEN, .ON_CHANGE, .CLOCK (time-driven triggers) or .ON_EVENT_UPDATED (Calendar events).
*/
function deleteTriggers_(triggerType) {
  // version 1.1, written by --Hyde, 27 June 2020
  //  - use getUserTriggers(ss) instead of getProjectTriggers()
  // version 1.0, written by --Hyde, 7 May 2020
  //  - initial version
  var triggers = ScriptApp.getUserTriggers(SpreadsheetApp.getActive());
  for (var i = 0, numTriggers = triggers.length; i < numTriggers; i++) {
    if (triggers[i].getEventType() === triggerType) {
      ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(triggers[i]);
    }
  }
}

/**
* Shows error.message in a pop-up and throws the error.
*
* @param {Error} error The error to show and throw.
*/
function showAndThrow_(error) {
  // version 1.0, written by --Hyde, 16 April 2020
  //  - initial version
  var stackCodeLines = String(error.stack).match(/\d+:/);
  if (stackCodeLines) {
    var codeLine = stackCodeLines.join(', ').slice(0, -1);
  } else {
    codeLine = error.stack;
  }
  showMessage_(error.message + ' Code line: ' + codeLine, 30);
  throw error;
}

/**
* Shows a message in a pop-up.
*
* @param {String} message The message to show.
* @param {Number} timeoutSeconds Optional. The number of seconds before the message goes away. Defaults to 5.
*/
function showMessage_(message, timeoutSeconds) {
  // version 1.0, written by --Hyde, 16 April 2020
  //  - initial version
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast(message, 'Auto Move Rows', timeoutSeconds || 5);
}
```

Comment: You did not provide the code  of the function for which you speak of `moveRowsAndSortSheet_` but if you are using the event object you might like to take a look at them to see how different that they are for different triggers.

Comment: Hi Cooper thanks for your reply. I've edited the post with the full code. Yes I have looked at the event object comparing the difference between the different triggers. I've learned, on_edit and on_form submit triggers have a 'range' object passed but on_change does not. However I'm still no further forward. Any help appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Where is the error line?

Comment: Please create a [mcve] while allows us to reproduce the problem without having to go through all of your code

Comment: I have edited the question with a minimal reproducible example which is still giving an error 'Auto Move Rows
Cannot read property 'getLastRow' of undefined Code line: 267'        ```event.rowEnd = e.range.getLastRow();```

Answer (score 1):

`event.rowEnd = e.range.getLastRow(1); event.columnStart = event.range.getColumn(); event.columnEnd = e.range.getLastRow();`

There is no `range` listed [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#change) for an onChange Event.

Also the first getLastRow() has a parameter which is wrong.

Comment: Personally, I think you're code is way too complex for an onEdit.

Comment: Sorry but I'm very new to script, correct me if I'm wrong but the following is the onChange event ```var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    event.range = ss.getActiveRange();
    event.rowStart = event.range.getRow();
    event.rowEnd = e.range.getLastRow();
    event.columnStart = event.range.getColumn();
    event.columnEnd = e.range.getLastRow();
    event.changeType = e.changeType;
    event.eventType = 'ON_CHANGE';
  } else { // triggered by some other change type
    return null;
  }``` can you please help, if the change will happen in column 21, how do I state this range?